# Cordova Contacts Plugin ContactFindOptions

Tags: javascript, cordova, contacts

I am using the Cordova for my app and I am trying to populate a listview with the user's contacts. I am using the ContactFindOption() function and I tried the example code.

Here is my code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
    filter = ["displayName","phoneNumber"];   // return contact.displayName field

    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

var contactsArray = [];

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].displayName) {
            contactArray.push(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
    alert(contactsArray);
}
```

When I run the app, there is a console log which says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you hav'nt define the callback function for onError, like you have done with "onSuccess" function

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the contacts plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-contacts.git
```

Comment: When I install this I get an error while fetching the plugin. I don't think it's the right way?

Comment: Yeah for some reason that did not work for me either. I made the fix in the answer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot hopefully this works. I'll make sure to accept ur answer if it does

Answer (score 0):

You've set filter to `["displayName","phoneNumber"];` this is incorrect.

The documentation for this is a little off. Heres what you want to do.

First and foremost you need to create an `onError` function for the find. As this is a REQUIRED function. You can do this the same way you've done your `onSuccess` function.

Secondly, your `filter = ["displayName","phoneNumber"];` is incorrect. Instead of `filter` you need to declare `fields = ["displayName","phoneNumber"];`. This will return only the displayName and phoneNumber fields from your contacts.

Here is what your complete code should look like.

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // there is no need to provide this as it will return all anyway if not passed in
    options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
    var fields = ["displayName","phoneNumber"];   //return displayName and phoneNumber FIELDS

    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

var contactsArray = [];

function onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].displayName) {
            contactArray.push(contacts[i]);
            //can also be done like this
            //contactArray[i] = contacts[i];
        }
    }
    alert(contactsArray);
}

function onError(){
  alert('there was an error finding contacts
}
```